# Phantom comment persisting across refreshes

Tags: bug, comments

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113657/notepad-crashed-and-overwrote-file-with-empty-version), the "show 1 more comment" link appears. Clicking it makes it disappear and shows no comments.

Normally I'd chalk this off to a comment being deleted around the same time, except it persists across page reloads (animated GIF):

[image]

Note: There's a fragment, `#39113657`, in that URL. I verified that wasn't related to the issue. It's in the GIF but I continued to see the issue after removing it.

So, yeah. Weird.

Comment: I've seen this a few times, pretty sure the value is cached and sometimes gets out of sync.

Comment: Those are comments left by a spammer or just ordinary user having their account destroyed. I caught one during the act so pretty sure it's the same thing.